# Loopback 3 crashes when trying to validate a model attached to User base model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I'm stuck at the validation process of my API. I want to validate multiple objects before storing them into the DB. I've created a function that I can call in my remote method in order to handle the validation.

The function below is working as excepted only the Account validation is causing trouble. My Loopback API crashed if the account object is not valid. Very weird because I do exactly the same with the other 2 models?

I've tried many things but nothing is working. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

```
 async function validate() {
  vehicle.isValid(function(valid) {
    if (!valid)
      throw (vehicle.errors);
  });
  repairJob.isValid(function(valid) {
    if (!valid){
      console.log(repairJob.errors);
      throw (repairJob.errors);
    }
  });
  account.isValid(function(valid) {
    if (!valid){
      console.log(account.errors);
      throw (account.errors);
    }
  });
}
```

Output from console:

> Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
>   Errors {
>    password: [ 'can\'t be blank' ],
>    email: [ 'can\'t be blank', 'can\'t be blank' ] }
>
> /Users/xxx/Development/xxx/xxx-api-v2/common/models/job.js:105
>            throw (account.errors);
>            ^
>   [object Object]
>   [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Can you please add a little context? Yet, I assume from the error log that your function is attempting to perform a login procedure and the `password` field is missing, maybe that's the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your account.json, you might have mentioned `"base": "User"`, you inherited account model from user model.As you can see below is the user.json where email and password properities are made `required:true` and so the loopback throws the error.You can change this in account.json by making email and password `required:false` if you dont want these two fields to be mandatory.Orelse check your request whether these two fileds have value.[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Validating-model-data.html) you can use `isValid` method

> To invoke the validation constraints explicitly

The same loopback will do automatically each time model instance is created or updated.
As I understand the `account` model has set `"base": "User"` and you can't have a user without a password or email.

Can you add how `account` look like before calling `isValid` function?